# Rails time_zone_select dropdown shows GMT instead of UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I created a model with time:time and time_zone:string. Specifically, I created using:

```
rails generate scaffold Alarm time:time time_zone:string
```

And I created a form as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@alarm) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br />
    <%= f.time_select :time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time_zone %><br />
    <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone,
        ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones,
        default: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I see the form, time_zone_select shows a dropdown containing bunch of time zones in GMT not in UTC (e.g. "(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time").

I thought by default, the time zones are shown in UTC. How do I make it show in UTC (e.g. (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time) instead?

This is a fresh project and I didn't touch any configuration file.

And I'm using ruby-1.9.3-p0, rails 3.2.6 and pg 0.13.2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Times are stored in UTC but displayed in your local timezone.

To revert the time back to UTC within the view, use this method :

```
local_to_utc(time, dst=true)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-local_to_utc

Or change it globally in your `application.rb` :

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = "UTC"
```

This determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc for Rails, although Active Record defaults to :local when used outside of Rails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if you understood my question correctly. I wasn't talking about the time not being displayed in UTC, but time zones in the combobox not being displayed in UTC. For example, if you go to http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1/, the combobox in the picture shows:
(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
(UTC-09:00) Alaska
...
But in my combobox, it shows:
(GMT-10:00) Hawaii
(GMT-09:00) Alaska
...
Hope that clarified the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. best I can offer is this : `config.active_record.default_timezone = "UTC"`

Comment: That didn't work either. Thanks though! I'll keep digging around.

Comment: Any luck on this? I have the same problem